# install multi module maven project

Tags: maven

parent project maven

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${revision}</version>
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <revision>0.1.10-SNAPSHOT</revision>
</properties>
```

child 1 module

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>module1</artifactId>
```

child 2 module

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>module2</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

after I installed parent project success
and download module2 I got error

> Could not find artifact groupId:artifactId:pom:${revision} in nexus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `${revision}` as a version number, you need to use the flatten maven plugin to replace the version number before it is uploaded.

Comment: my module1 is a springboot web service and module2 tend to be deployed to nexus, so when I deploy project, module1 should be ignored, how should I build my to sub modules?

Comment: Sorry, is this a new question? Then please ask a new question on Stackoverflow instead of asking it in the comments.